# Using ajax to load a certain number of items from a DataObject each time a button is clicked?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `See more` button which when clicked I want to be able to load another 3 Past Events onto the default 3 past events that show on page load, and then if clicked again, add another 3 etc.

The code below works but is multiplying the number for some reason e.g if I press the "See more" button as the code is now, it returns 18 `past events` when it should only return 6 `past events`...

If I `dd($amountOfCurrentPastEvents + 3)` I get `int(6)` returned 3 times,  6 x 3 = 18. e.g:

[image]

Question is why is it getting called three times? What am I doing wrong here?

**DashboardPage.php**

```
class DashboardPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'pastEvent',
        'seeMorePastEvents',
        'pasteventfilter',
        'LimitedPastEvents'
    );

    public function LimitedPastEvents()
    {
        return PastEvent::get()->limit(3);
    }

    public function seeMorePastEvents() {
        if (Director::is_ajax()) {
            // Gets the amount of past events that are display on the page at present
            $amountOfCurrentPastEvents = $_POST['events'];
            // Adds 3 onto how ever many past events are currently showing
            $PastEvents = PastEvent::get()->limit($amountOfCurrentPastEvents + 3);
            return $this->customise(array(
                'Results' => $PastEvents
            ))->renderWith('AjaxPastEvents');

        }
    }

    ...

}
```

**DashboardPage.ss**

```
<% loop LimitedPastEvents %>
    <div class="past-event-results">
        <div class="col-md-4 no-padding past-event">
            <a href="$Link">
                <div class="live-workouts-wrapper">
                    <div class="on-demand-image" style="background-image: url($ThemeDir/images/vid-3.jpg);">
                        <div class="play-icon"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="on-demand-info text-center">
                        <div class="on-demand-location">
                            <span class="pin-icon"></span><span>$BranchLocation.Name, $BranchLocation.City</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="on-demand-date-time">
                            <span class="time-icon"></span>
                            <span>{$EventDate.Day} {$EventDate.ShortMonth} {$EventDate.Format(dS)} $Time.Nice</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <strong>$EventName</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end_loop %>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-seemore">SEE MORE<b class="btn-icon btn-down"></b></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery - Located on DashboardPage.ss**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pastEventCount;
    $('.btn-seemore').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Gets the amount of past events that are currently displayed on the page
        pastEventCount = $('.past-event').length;
        console.log(pastEventCount);
        $.post('/dashboard/seeMorePastEvents', {events: pastEventCount}, function(data) {
            $('.past-event-results').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the code adds the new content to `.past-event-results` with `$('.past-event-results').html(data);`, but the template has 3 `.past-event-results` divs to begin with.

The data returned by the ajax function (6 PastEvent entries) is added to 3 divs, making the results show 18 items.

The following loop creates 3 `past-event-results` divs to begin with:

```
<% loop LimitedPastEvents %>
    <div class="past-event-results">
    ...
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

You might want to take this div outside of the loop:

```
<div class="past-event-results">
<% loop LimitedPastEvents %>
    ...
<% end_loop %>
</div>
```

This will mean there is only ever one `past-event-results` div.

I would also recommend changing the `seeMorePastEvents()` function to only return the new items, rather than all the existing items plus the new items each time. This will save on data that needs to be passed back and slightly improve the server fetch.

To make this change we first need to change the limit function to only fetch 3 items and start the fetch from the `$amountOfCurrentPastEvents` point.

```
$PastEvents = PastEvent::get()->limit(3, $amountOfCurrentPastEvents);
```

The `DataList` `limit()` function can take [2 parameters](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataList.html#_limit):

```
limit(integer $limit, integer $offset = 0)
```

We use offset to change the fetch start point.

We then change our JavaScript to append the retrieved data rather than overwrite the existing events:

```
$('.past-event-results').append(data);
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense now! Thank you so much, it's working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like a JS issue.

You might have x3 AJAX requests being sent - if you break out your browser's debugger, how many XHR requests are being sent to SilverStripe?

Also check the generated markup. I suspect your JS logic should be appending to the `.past-event-results` DOM node itself, and not appending to its contents which is essentially what the jQuery `html` method is doing for you.